# astyle have problem with formatting templates

Tags: c++, coding-style, astyle

It convert:

```cpp
template <typename T,
            typename ...Args,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
void function(T in, Args... args)
{

}
```

To :

```cpp
template <typename T,
            typename ...Args,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
                        void function(T in, Args... args)
{

}
```

It have problem with:

```cpp
typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>
```

`astyle` do not put function in middle when i add another template parameter:

```cpp
template <typename T,
            typename ...Args,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>,
            typename C>
void function(T in, Args... args)
{

}
```

My `astyle` options is  [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mg-ramezani/a4850ce614b4578bb5788ed10b80c4b7/raw/9b44f8ece7b711f683e570851b3fa4c9031ce33e/artistic_style.astylerc) options.

- Artistic Style Version 3.1, using with Qt Creator IDE on Linux (archlinux 5.7.4-arch1-1).

How can avoid putting it in the middle ?

Comment: Have you considered using [ClangFormat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) instead? In my experience it is greatly superior to `astyle`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, Yes, I used it for about 3 months with [this configuration](https://gist.github.com/mg-ramezani/a5e98d665da2748508e45d2bad230c03), But it is really slow on large files and have some problem when i try to use languages other than English in my code (Like a comment in farsi) and some other thing about styling which clang-format doesn't have it.